# How to write Max(L)<1 without using MAX func in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, max

I have an optimization problem which is solved with `fmincon`. In this problem I have a constraint that says every element of the vector `L` must be less than or equal to 1. So basicaly I can add this constraint like this

```
C=max(L)-1 ; % C(X)<0
```

But now I want to write the above constraint with out using `Max` function.
**Any idea?**

Comment: `all(L<1)`? but why not `max`?

Comment: Yes I want all (L<1) but without using `max` function. I think it makes my NLP a DNLP if I use `max` @user3528438

Comment: maybe like this: `sum(L(L>1)) == 0` returns `1` if all elements are less or equal to 1. returns `0` if there is at least one element greater than 1. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: This will work. Thanks. However, I defined new optimisation variables and bound it to its max value (VUB) and then defined the inequality constraint as an equality constraint.  This made the optimisation process faster. @eventHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every element of the vector L must be less than or equal to 1.

This should be written as a *set* of constraints, not a single constraint. Artificially bundling the constraints L(1)<=1, L(2)<=1, ... into one constraint is just going to cause more pain to the solver.

**Example with linear constraints**: minimizing -x(1)*x(2) subject to x(1)<=1 and x(2)<=1

```
fmincon(@(x) -x(1)*x(2), [0.5; 0.5], [1 0; 0 1], [1; 1])
```

(Here the simple form `fmincon(fun,x0,A,b)` is used.)

**Example with nonlinear constraints**: minimizing -x(1)*x(2) subject to x(1)^2+x(2)^2<=1 and x(1)+x(2)^2<=1

```
fmincon(@(x) -x(1)*x(2), [0.1; 0.1], [],[],[],[],[],[], @(x) deal([x(1)^2+x(2)^2-1; x(1)+x(2)^2-1],[]))
```

Here the form `fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon)` is used, where nonlcon returns multiple inequality constraints and equality constraints. Specifically, the first output of the nonlinear constraint function is `[x(1)^2+x(2)^2-1; x(1)+x(2)^2-1]`; both of these are required to be <=0. The second output, nonlinear equality constraints, is an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Alternatively, I defined new optimisation variables and bound it to its max value (VUB) and then defined the inequality constraint as an equality constraint.  This made the optimisation process faster. @homegrown-tomato